# Is RDBMS a good option to store output data of Association Rule Mining Algorithm?

Tags: database, associations, rdbms, apriori, nosql

I am currently applying FP growth algorithm on a relatively large dataset and I would prefer to persist the Support and Confidence output of frequent itemsets. When I began to design a RDBMS schema to store the output data, the schema became overly complex.
This made me think , is RDBMS even a good choice to store these kind of data or should we prefer something like NoSQL ?

Thanks